# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider on a controller in Angularjs 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and learning now .I have a controller as 
EventlistController.js

```
    eventsApp.controller('EventListController',function EventListController($scope,$location,$eventData){
$scope.events=eventData.getAllEvents();
});
```

my app.js is as follows
`

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngSanitize','ngResource','ngRoute']).config(
    function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/events',{
        templateUrl:'templates/EventList.html',
        controller:'EventListController'
        });
});
```

And EventData Service is as follows

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function ($resource) {
    return {
        getEvent: function () {
            var resource = $resource('http://localhost:8001/api/event/:id', { id: '@id' });
            return resource.get({ id: 1 });
        },
        save: function (event) {
            var resource = $resource.get('http://localhost:8001/api/event/getNextEventId');
            event.id = resource.get();
            console.log(event.id);
           return resource.save();
        },
        getAllEvents: function() {
            var resource = $resource('http://localhost:8001/api/event');
            return resource.query();
        }
    }
});
```

when I hit the route `http://localhost:8000/#/events` I get `[$injector:unpr]` error. I've gone through the documentation for this one. not sure whats the error was. Any pointers on what am I missing here?

Comment: Nope..i am just running as is

Comment: can you pls show the sequence in which you have included the js files in html?

Comment: @Rakesh, its too long for a comment to show the include files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created eventData and you are using $eventData.
Try using eventData only. you were injecting incorrect service.
And you may skip writing this name 'EventListController' .

```
eventsApp.controller('EventListController',function($scope,$location,eventData){
$scope.events=eventData.getAllEvents();
});
```

Comment: okay..whay and when we should not use the $ before the dependencies? Is it like for user defined services, $ should be excluded?

Comment: you can accept it as anwer if it is helpful :). happy coding.

Comment: @Programmerzzz: Angular expect the name given my us only. Sometimes by mistake we missell :)